# How to append a rounded corners rectangle

Tags: d3.js, svg, polygon

I have a rectangle below using d3.js. How to make all corners of the polygon that i appended rounded using d3.js. Thank you

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 500)
  .append("g")
 

svg.append("polygon")
   .attr("points", "214 185,302 335,546 374,688 260,630 92,361 57")
   .style("fill", "green")
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("strokeWidth", "10px");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use this to get the d attribute of a path with rounded corners: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/bJZRPb In the case of your example you can use this d attribute: `M221.542,178.433 Q214,185 219.060,193.625L296.940,326.375 Q302,335 311.875,336.578L536.125,372.422 Q546,374 553.798,367.740L680.202,266.260 Q688,260 684.737,250.547L633.263,101.453 Q630,92 620.084,90.710L370.916,58.290 Q361,57 353.458,63.567Z`

Comment: Alternatively you may want to use quadratic bézier curves with the control point on the vertexes of the polygon

Comment: or use a rect element which can have rounded corners in markup.